# Multiple inheritance with one class and interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

My intended goal is to extend multiple classes from an existing library by a fixed set of attributes and methods (whose names will not overlap).

The straight forward solution would be simple inheritance: derive the library class and add the attributes/methods. But it would be quite repetitive as the attributes and methods will be the same for all derived classes. It would be better to create an auxilliary class with all attributes and methods I need and simply derive the extended classes from both the library class and the auxilliary class.

However, as it seems there is no multiple inheritance in Kotlin comparable to C++ , I wanted to use interfaces to make it work, where the interface would hold all the attributes and methods I need.

I have started with the following simplistic code to test interfaces:

```
open class LibraryClass{
    var x: Int = 0

    fun setMyX(x_: Int){
        x = x_
    }
}

interface MyInterface{
    var y: Int
    var z: Int
    var abc: Int

    fun myMethod(y_: Int){
        y = y_
        z = y*y
    }
} 

class InheritanceTest: LibraryClass(), MyInterface{    
    fun print(){
    println("My values: $x, $y, $z")
    }
}

fun main(){
    var test = InheritanceTest()
    test.setMyX(1)
    test.myMethod(5)
    test.print()    
}
```

If I try to compile this code, I will get the following error message:

```
error: class 'InheritanceTest' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract var y: Int defined in MyInterface
```

Some research showed that I need to override the interface's attributes in the primary constructor of the derived class:

```
class InheritanceTest(override var y: Int, override var z: Int, override var abc: Int)
```

and then

```
var test = InheritanceTest(2,3,0)
```

Overriding all(?) interface attributes (even unused ones) in the derived class seems quite repetitive (and it's not possible to initialize attributes in the interface either), which basically beats the purpose of why I originally intended to use interfaces: to save repetition.
(Except for methods, which seem not to have to be overridden as long as one class and (multiple) interfaces do not share methods of the same name).

My interposed question is: Is this the only way to do it or solve the error?

Then I found something else to try out in the interface:

```
var fgh: Int 
    get()  { return fgh }
    set(v) { fgh = v }
```

No overriding necessary so far. But I could not yet get how to actually use the attribute fgh in either a method or by setting a value.

When I try to set fgh by `test.fgh = 100` in `main()`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at MyInterface$DefaultImpls.setFgh(
```

Then trying to use `test.setFgh(100)` (since the previous error message implies the method exists) yields:

```
error: unresolved reference: setFgh
```

Trying to define `setFgh(v: Int) {fgh = v}`  results in:

```
error: platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (setFgh(I)V):
    fun <set-fgh>(v: Int): Unit defined in MyInterface
    fun setFgh(v: Int): Unit defined in MyInterface
```

Alright, defining a differently named method similar to `myMethod()`:

```
fun myOtherMethod(v: Int){    
    fgh = v 
    z = fgh * fgh
}
```

And then using `myOtherMethod(10)` in `main()` gives again:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at MyInterface$DefaultImpls.setFgh
```

So, I'm now really lost as to what do in order to get a non-repetitive working solution for extending multiple classes with the same attributes and methods.

Edit: 
I now understand that interfaces aren't exactly what I was going for, as one has to implement (not override, which took me a while to get as it is done by the keyword "override") everything in the derived classes.

Comment: `fgh's set` is recursively calling itself, causing infinite recursion on finite hardware, which leads to `[return address] stack overflow`. You can't just make it work like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right track with your first try. You really have to override the attributes in the interface, but it doesn't have to be done in the constructor. You can do it in the class body and that way you can add a default value for them (not only can, but you must). If you make that class open you can then extend from it in all your classes.

```
open class InheritanceTest: LibraryClass(), MyInterface {
    override var y: Int = 0
    override var z: Int = 0
    override var abc: Int = 0

    fun print() {
        println("My values: $x, $y, $z")
    }
}
```

With this class your original main will print `My values: 1, 5, 25`, and you will be able to inherit from this class without having to override/initialize anything (but you can use the `init` block to customize your superclass). For example:

```
class MyClass : InheritanceTest() {
    init {
        myMethod(4)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val test = MyClass()
    test.setMyX(2)
    test.print()
}
```

will print `My values: 2, 4, 16`

I hope I understood your question correctly and could help :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason behind `StackOverflowError` is that you are recursively accessing the property in your setter and getter:

```
var fgh: Int 
    get()  { return fgh } // recursive call to getFgh()
    set(v) { fgh = v } // recursive call to setFgh(v)
```

In order to access the property's [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) in the custom accessors, you need to use the `field` identifier:

```
var fgh: Int 
    get()  { return field }
    set(v) { field = value }
```

However in this case custom accessors are redundant, the point was to introduce the `field` identifier. Also this still won't work in interfaces as properties in interfaces can't be initialized or can't have backing fields.

In order to achieve more or less what you want (if I understood you correctly), you can either create an in-between-class, that extends `LibraryClass`, implements `MyInterface` and can be extended by `InheritanceTest`:

```
// abstract or open
abstract class InBetweenClass : LibraryClass(), MyInterface {
    override var y: Int = 1
    override var z: Int = 2
    override var abc: Int = 3
}

class InheritanceTest : InBetweenClass() {    
    fun print() {
        println("My values: $x, $y, $z")
    }
}
```

or use [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation) to provide a default implementation for the `MyInterface` properties:

```
class DefaultImplementation : MyInterface {
    override var y: Int = 1
    override var z: Int = 2
    override var abc: Int = 3
}

class InheritanceTest : LibraryClass(), MyInterface by DefaultImplementation() {    
    fun print(){
        println("My values: $x, $y, $z")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any concrete class implementing an interface must implement all the members of the interface, otherwise it doesn't fulfill the contract. If you have attributes in the interface that you don't implement in your class, then your class doesn't satisfy the interface, hence the compile error. Any user of the interface expects the actual instance to provide all the functionality of the interface, that's why the compiler enforces it.

If you want to share some fields but not all, you can create a hierarchy of interfaces, and just implement the ones you need. I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve here and why there would be so much redundancy in the attributes you want to add, though.

Another way to extend library classes to add methods would be to define [extension functions/properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) on the library classes, but you'll need to repeat some stuff and you won't be able to store state there.

If you do need to store state, and you don't want to re-implement all fields manually, you can also use the [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html) mechanism.
Create a single class implementing your common interface and provide an instance of this class when creating your custom extension classes for the lib. Then again, it seems to be the solution to the wrong problem, and it'd be better to really understand what you're trying to achieve here.